# How to select the child node in TreeView in c# windows form

Tags: c#, treeview

I have one tree view in my windows form. I use the following function to select the node in that treeView.

```
private void FindAndSelect(TreeNodeCollection collection, object toSelect)
    {
        //problem in this line becouse while converting the toSelect into IstructuredEntity is showing null.

        var entityToSelect = toSelect as Decoupling::IStructureEntity;

        if (entityToSelect == null) //just select the Structure root
        {
            _treeView.SelectedNode = _treeView.Nodes[0];
            return;
        }
        foreach (TreeNode tn in collection)
        {
            var treeNodeEntity = tn.Tag as IStructureEntity;
            if (treeNodeEntity != null && treeNodeEntity.Id == entityToSelect.Id)
            {

                _treeView.SelectedNode = tn;

            }

            FindAndSelect(tn.Nodes, toSelect);
        }
    }
```

But the above function is only able to select the parent node in treeView and I want to select and highlight the child.
Can anyone please guide me as to what I need to change for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TreeView.Nodes** will only give you the Parent Nodes. You might have to implement ParentNode.ChildNode to get the childnodes in your tree. Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.childnodes(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
{
   // get parent node here
   foreach (TreeNode child in tn.Nodes)
   {
     //get child node here
   }
}
```

Comment: i already tried this but i am not able to highlight the child node. parent node i am easily able to select and highlight but child node is not able to select. Any other suggestion?