# How to get the name of the selected child node in a treeview list in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using the command:

```
selecteddirectory = treeViewDirectory.SelectedNode.Text;
```

However this always gives the name of the parent node and not the child node selected.
How to go about doing this?

Comment: .SelectedNode.Name

Comment: Treeview give you the the parent node. You need to implement ParentNode.ChildNode

Comment: Reference link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.childnodes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_TreeNode_ChildNodes

Comment: Review the below Answer [How to Select the Child Node in TreeView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937895/how-to-select-the-child-node-in-treeview-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the treeview_AfterSelect event to select the child node.

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(selectedNodeText);
        }
```

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
selecteddirectory = treeViewDirectory.SelectedNode.Name;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode?